# copy particular index data of NSMutablearray to another one in swift

Tags: swift

i had try many time but i am not figure it out that how can i copy particular index data to another NSMutableArray
Here, is my code

```
for var i = 0 ; i < arrayData.count ; i++
    {
        if (arrayData.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("id")!.isEqualToString(id))
        {
            self.title = arrayData.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("name") as? String
            println("data match")
            arraySelectedData = arrayData.objectAtIndex(i) as NSMutableArray
            println("\(arrayData.objectAtIndex(i))")
        }
    }
}
```

arraData and ArraySelectedData are NSMutableArray
here is the arraydata

```
      {
    cuisine = Beverages;
    discount = "50%";
    "ex_date" = "Saturday, October 31, 2015";
    id = 1;
    image = "http://192.168.168.224/restaurant-app/siteuploads/dealimg/1435723747_ice-cream-2.png";
    location = "Andheri West, Mumbai";
    name = "Awesome Icecream";
    "rest_id" = 2;
    title = "Giant Discount for Summer";
},
    {
    cuisine = "Fast Food, Mughlai";
    discount = "25%";
    "ex_date" = "Saturday, October 31, 2015";
    id = 3;
    image = "http://192.168.168.224/restaurant-app/siteuploads/dealimg/1435726233_logoread.png";
    location = "Andheri West, Mumbai";
    name = "Food for Everyone";
    "rest_id" = 3;
    title = "Non Veg Bonanza";
}
```

)
Now copy the one index data of ArrayData to ArraySelectedData

Comment: What is there in your array? Looks like the array is of dictionaries...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
let arraySelectedData = NSMutableArray()

for var i = 0 ; i < arrayData.count ; i++
    {
        if (arrayData.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("id")!.isEqualToString(id))
        {
            self.title = arrayData.objectAtIndex(i).valueForKey("name") as? String
            println("data match")
            arraySelectedData.addObject(arrayData.objectAtIndex(i) as NSDictionary)
            println("\(arraySelectedData)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it's give me the error like "AnyObject is not convertible to [AnyObject]" at arraySelectedData.addObject(arrayData.objectAtIndex(i)) line

Comment: did you tried like this arraySelectedData.addObject(arrayData.objectAtIndex(i) as NSMutableArray)

Comment: also we cant work with assumption, post the exact structure of arrayData and what you want to be added in arraySelectedData

Comment: i want to copy the one index data to arraySelected Array.

Comment: i am edit my question to show the structure od ArrayData.please see the update.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89548/discussion-between-chandra-vaghasiya-and-erik).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89635/discussion-between-chandra-vaghasiya-and-venkat).